# parseInt() causing returned value of javascript function to be 0.77 times expected result, radix specified as decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

I have the following calculation:

```
$(function() {
      $("#x").click( function()
           {
            var n1 = parseFloat(76790);
            var n2 = parseFloat(5.3/100);
            var n3 = parseFloat(1.6);
            n3 = parseInt(n3, 10);

            var result = n1*(n2+(n2*n3));

             $("#qid_185").val(result);
           }
      );
});
```

It is returning values which are 1.3 times the expected result. If I remove the parseInt line `n3 = parseInt(n3, 10);` values are as expected.

I realised that the parseint line isn't necessary so I can just remove it to fix it but I want to understand why this is happening? I'm specifying decimal in the radix.

[Js fiddle with parsint line](http://jsfiddle.net/2nv2N/)

[Js fiddle without parsint line](http://jsfiddle.net/2nv2N/1/)

Hit the X button to run the calculation - correct value is 10581.662, parsint value is 0.77 times this.

Comment: Because you're overwriting n3 with an integer and that is used in the calculation.

Comment: Not sure what else you expected...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parseFloat(1.6) => 76790 * ((5.3/100) + ((5.3/100)*1.6)) => 76790 * 0.1378 => 10581.662

parseInt(1.6, 10) => 76790 * ((5.3/100) + ((5.3/100)*1)) => 76790 * 0.106 => 8139.74
```

The difference is parseFloat gives you the decimal fraction value, parseInt cuts off any decimal point(s).

To further elaborate on having '10' as the radix, I believe you misunderstood the use of the term 'decimal' as a radix. This means that it is base 10, which is your standard number system as "integers" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal), not "decimal fractions" such as the '.6' in 1.6.

Other examples would be the following:

radix of 2 - Binary, radix of 8 - Octal, radix of 16 - Hex

Comment: Ah I didn't understand that parseInt gave and Integer only, though as I write that I realise how very silly that was of me!